# Does optimizing require.js/backbone app css files through r.js include cdn @imports

Tags: css, optimization, backbone.js, requirejs, r.js

i'm including external font css (Google Font) on my css file using @import

**styles.css**

```
/* Feel free to use @import. r.js will merge them, when building */
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"; //this is included
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chewy); //would this be included?
...
```

would r.js include the remote file and optimize it? r.js doesn't have a full documentation on its switches and settings or I am just missing something? or i just reconfigure my build to include the remote/cdn file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as of `2.1.5` I'm getting this output:

```
Optimizing (standard.keepLines) CSS file: /.../style/style-all.css
/.../style/style-all.css
Cannot inline css import, skipping: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chewy
```

Analysing [source code on github](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/jslib/optimize.js#L48) suggests that it only supports relative paths.

Comment: would opening up this issue/feature on github(https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/issues?state=open) would be a good idea? if not then I would use any css precompilation (sass or less) so that they will be the ones who compile/minify the css and that includes non relative paths and urls

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there was a technical reason for only allowing relative paths, but it's worth asking on project's page.